# View and Combine 2 rows in 1 from same table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem to view my data as I want,

```
IDFlight | Dep1 | Des1| Date  | IDFlight2 | Dep2 | Des2 | Date   | Price
---------+------+-----+-------+-----------+------+------+--------+--------
    2    |  AYT | PRN |20.3.15|     3     | PRN  | AYT  | 27.3.15|  150
    2    |  AYT | PRN |20.3.15|     4     | PRN  | AYT  | 30.3.15|  150
    1    |  AYT | PRN |23.3.15|     4     | PRN  | AYT  | 30.3.15|  150 
    1    |  AYT | PRN |17.3.15|     3     | PRN  | AYT  | 27.3.15|  150
```

So search query was with Dates +- 3 days both for 2 flights.

in my case every flight is registered alone in table Flights, each flight has his flight number and his direction, date and pricing(e.g return and one way).
now the problem here is, when user selects the return option, there will be displayed 2 flights in one row, (flight 1 go to destination, flight 2 return from destination) also there is a differences between dates line in the example in the picture.

what I am trying to achieve is displaying data like in example above , that every "one way " record should match with the " return " record. even if the first data is repeated.

I have done a lot of research but no result,
also I tried to do with a view but no success

I tried union no success.

```
@prmDepDay int, @prmDesDay int, @prmDateDep datetime, @prmFrom int, @prmTo int, 
@prmDateRe datetime, @prmFromRe int, @prmToRe int, @prmTotalRe int 
AS
BEGIN
DROP TABLE departureflights

SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT 
             t_flights.idflight, 
             t_flights.flightnumber, 
             t_departureairport.depairportname, 
             t_destinationairport.desairportname, 
             t_flights.startdate, 
             t_flights.totalseats 
  INTO       departureflights 
  FROM       t_flights 
  INNER JOIN t_departureairport 
  ON         t_flights.iddepartureairport = t_departureairport.iddepartureairport 
  INNER JOIN t_destinationairport 
  ON         t_flights.iddestinationairport = t_destinationairport.iddestinationairport 
  INNER JOIN t_flightdirections 
  ON         t_flights.iddirection = t_flightdirections.iddirection 
  WHERE      t_departureairport.iddepartureairport = @prmFrom 
  AND        t_destinationairport.iddestinationairport = @prmTo 
  AND        startdate >= Dateadd(day,-@prmDepDay,@prmDateDep) 
  AND        startdate <= Dateadd(day,@prmDepDay,@prmDateDep) 
             --and TotalSeats>= @prmTotal 
  ORDER BY   t_flights.startdate

  DROP TABLE returnflights        

  SELECT     t_flights.idflight, 
             t_flights.flightnumber              AS ReFlightNumber, 
             t_departureairport.depairportname   AS ReDepAirportName, 
             t_destinationairport.desairportname AS ReDesAirportName, 
             t_flights.enddate , 
             t_flights.totalseats 
  INTO       returnflights 
  FROM       t_flights 
  INNER JOIN t_departureairport 
  ON         t_flights.iddepartureairport = t_departureairport.iddepartureairport 
  INNER JOIN t_destinationairport 
  ON         t_flights.iddestinationairport = t_destinationairport.iddestinationairport 
  INNER JOIN t_flightdirections 
  ON         t_flights.iddirection = t_flightdirections.iddirection 
  WHERE      t_departureairport.iddepartureairport = @prmFromRe 
  AND        t_destinationairport.iddestinationairport = @prmToRe 
  AND        enddate >= Dateadd(day,-@prmDesDay,@prmDateRe) 
  AND        enddate <= Dateadd(day,@prmDesDay,@prmDateRe) 
  AND        totalseats>= @prmTotalRe 
  ORDER BY   t_flights.enddate
```

Comment: maybe cross join helps you ?

Comment: You have this posting listed as C#.  You can execute the store SQL procedure from C# and then return the results.  This can be accomplished easier in C# than with an SQL query.  After the join is performed, you can create multiple rows from a single "join result".  If you can post the results of the stored SQL procedure I can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you join the t_flights table with itself you should get both the outgoing and returning flight info in one row.

```
SELECT journey_out.idflight IDFlight, 
    journey_out.iddepartureairport Dep1, 
    journey_out.iddestinationairport Des1, 
    journey_out.enddate Date1,
    journey_return.idflight IDFlight2, 
    journey_return.iddepartureairport Dep2, 
    journey_return.iddestinationairport Dep2, 
    journey_return.enddate Date2
FROM t_flights journey_out
INNER JOIN t_flights journey_return 
    ON journey_out.iddestinationairport = journey_return.iddepartureairport 
    AND journey_out.enddate < journey_return.startdate
ORDER BY journey_out.startdate
```

The first join condition makes sure that the flight is going home from the correct airport, and the second condition makes sure that the return journey does not start before the arrival.

If you want to see the one way options in the same result set as the return options you can change it to a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.